# AspectJ Pointcut On All Executions of a Method Without Specific Annotations

Tags: java, aspectj

How do I write a pointcut that triggers when a method, e.g. all setters on MyClass, is executed but that method is missing some specific annotations e.g. @Ann1 and @Ann2

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Ann1 {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Ann2 {}

public class Code {
  public void setFoo() {}
  @Ann1 public void setBar() {}
  @Ann2 public void setBoo() {}
  @Ann1 @Ann2 public void setFar() {}
}

aspect X {
  before(): execution(!@Ann1 !@Ann2 * set*(..)) {}
}
```

Now compile it:

```
ajc -1.5 -showWeaveInfo Code.java

Join point 'method-execution(void Code.setFoo())' in Type 'Code' (Code.java:10) advised by before advice from 'X' (Code.java:17)
```

See that only `setFoo()` is advised. A pointcut like this:

```
before(): execution(!@Ann1 * set*(..)) || execution(!@Ann2 * set*(..)) {}
```

would match where either @Ann1 or @Ann2 is missing (so the first 3 setters).